# ¿De dónde viene la diferente ortografía para "concejo" y "consejo"?

Tags: etimología

Me llama la atención la diferente ortografía para [*concejo*](http://dle.rae.es/consejo) y [*consejo*](http://dle.rae.es/consejo). Al parecer tienen la misma etimología latina en la palabra *consilium*. Si esto no fuese cierto,

> ¿la similitud es mera coincidencia?

Si tienen la misma etimología, entonces

> ¿cómo y cuándo se bifurcaron?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según la RAE, ambas palabras no tienen el mismo origen etimológico:

- "consejo" proviene del latín "consilium", que originalmente significaba "dictamen"
- "concejo" proviene del latín "concilium", cuyo significado era "asamblea".

De modo que su similitud se debe a la similitud de las palabras latinas de las que provienen ambos términos, y por tanto, en este caso, no surgió una "doble grafía" a partir de una misma palabra latina.

Sin embargo, la palabra "concilium" sí derivó en dos términos: "concejo" y "concilio".